# gradle compile library and modify its source

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've added this library to my gradle build and I would like to access it's code and modify it but when I open the class it tells me that it's a "compiled code".

Is there a way I can get a reference to the actual class with the code available for modifications??

here it the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "********"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.0.1@aar"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'

}
```

The specific library is this:

```
compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.0.1@aar"
```

Comment: Which library? How did you add it? Can you share your build.gradle file

Comment: To be able to modify sources without fear to lose your changes you have to clone sources from https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout, convert your project to multimodule project, change dependency to artifact to dependency of subproject

Comment: And of course you have to maintain now changes from original library if you want to be up to date with it

Comment: is this the only way?

Comment: Unfortunately aar contains compiled classes (apklib contained class sources). So this is only one way how to do it